# CUDA:out of memory error on darknet yolov1

Tags: cuda

I am trying to run darknet YOLOv1 code on GPU Tesla K40.

Everything was working fine a few days before with parameter "ARCH= --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20" in makefile.

But, Today when I did make again. "make" worked but on running YOLO's demo on video is giving following error[image: CUDA:OutOfMemoryError]

I tried different ARCH parameters like compute_30 , 35 , 52.. But nothing is working.

What coulde be the possible solutions?

Note: darknet yoloV2 is working fine. I am implementing the following blog : http://guanghan.info/blog/en/my-works/train-yolo/

Comment: Keeping in mind that [SO] is intended for *programming* questions, what are you trying to ask here?

Comment: Again, this is a perfectly valid (and interesting IMHO) question that has been closed for no apparent reason. Anyway, I found a solution that can be useful to quickly test the CUDA version of Yolo with low-end nVidia cards: `./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg yolov2-tiny.weights image.jpg`. This config uses about 300 megs of memory and thus can be used with XOrg and Compiz running also on my GTX 750.

Comment: I found this solution reading [the YOLO wiki page](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/wiki/YOLO:-Real-Time-Object-Detection). Yolov2-tiny weights can be downloaded [here](http://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov2-tiny.weights).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried modifying **cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg**?

It should look like the following:

```
[net]
batch=64
subdivisions=64
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1
...
```

The trick is making **batch** equal to **subdivisions**.